# MPAndroidChart grouped bar doesn't begin from left side

Tags: android, charts

I'm using latest version of MPAndroidChart. I'm trying to generate a grouped bar chart, following the example on this [link](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Setting-Data#grouped-barchart), but without success. The problem is the xAxis. Altought I set fromX = 0 , bars don't begin fit to left axis. It has an space between the left vertical line and the beginig of the first bar.

Here is my code:

```
BarChart barChart = (BarChart) view.findViewById(R.id.chartDesgFam);
ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
entries.add(new BarEntry(0,4f));
entries.add(new BarEntry(1,8f));
entries.add(new BarEntry(2,6f));
entries.add(new BarEntry(3,12f));
entries.add(new BarEntry(4,18f));
entries.add(new BarEntry(5,9f));

ArrayList<BarEntry> entries2 = new ArrayList<>();
entries2.add(new BarEntry(0,5f));
entries2.add(new BarEntry(1,6f));
entries2.add(new BarEntry(2,12f));
entries2.add(new BarEntry(3,5f));
entries2.add(new BarEntry(4,14f));
entries2.add(new BarEntry(5,3f));

BarDataSet dataset = new BarDataSet(entries, "Serie 1");
dataset.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 200));
BarDataSet dataset2 = new BarDataSet(entries2, "Serie 2");
dataset2.setColor(Color.rgb(200, 0, 0));

ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
labels.add("January");
labels.add("February");
labels.add("March");
labels.add("April");
labels.add("May");
labels.add("June");

XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setSpaceMin(0f);
        xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
        xAxis.setDrawLabels(true);
        xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);
        xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        xAxis.setLabelCount(labels.size());
        xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {
            @Override
            public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
                if (value>=0) {
                    if (value < labels.size() ) return labels.get((int) value);
                    else return "";
                }
                return "";
            }
        });

ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
dataSets.add(dataset);
dataSets.add(dataset2);

BarData data = new BarData(dataSets);

float groupSpace = 0.06f;
float barSpace = 0.02f; // x2 dataset
float barWidth = 0.45f; // x2 dataset
data.setBarWidth(barWidth);

barChart.setData(data);
barChart.groupBars(0, groupSpace, barSpace);
barChart.setFitBars(true);
barChart.invalidate();
```

In order to adjust the first bar to the left side, I need to put -0.2f in fromX parameter. I think It isn't for that, but I don't know why It doesn't begin from the left side. This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Try using `xAxis.setAxisMinimum()` with barWidth as part of the parameter. It looks like it needs to be shifted about barWidth/2.

Comment: It doesn't work. It is worst. If I set axis minimu, It slides the labels and repeat the first one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please follow code below to get it fixed:

```
chart.getXAxis().setAxisMinimum(0);
chart.getXAxis().setAxisMaximum(0 + chart.getBarData().getGroupWidth(groupSpace, barSpace) * groupCount);
```

where groupCount is total number of entries you are having in your dataset. You can get that as:

```
data.getDataSetCount();
```

Comment: Hope this works. Do let me know if you need to know something else buddy.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I doesn't work. As I answered to @Gavin Wright, if I change setAxisMinimun I get fitted the bars on the left side, but X-labels are totally off-centered and displaced from the grouped bars. And, another problem is the first label is repeated.

Comment: Finally I get It!!!. Your answer put me in the right direction. After a lot of try-error the solution was  setAxisMinimum(0),  setAxisMaximun(BarEntry1.size()+0.1f); Thanks for your help.